# Как установить звук push-уведомления

Tags: android, firebase, push-уведомления, google-cloud-messages

Я хочу при отправке push-уведомления с сервера указывать имя мелодии и что  бы при получении сообщения проигрывалась нужная мелодия. В случае когда приложение запущено -  я могу отловить входящее сообщение и после чего самостоятельно сформировать `notification`. Но в случае когда приложение не включено - я не управляю этим процессом. У меня получилось передавать имя иконки для сообщения которая лежит  в **res/drawable** - и это работает. Мелодию же я положил в **res/raw/jingle_bells_sms.ogg** но это не сработало.

Вопрос: возможно ли устанавливать свой звук для таких  сообщений впринципе, в какой папке эти звуки должны лежать и где я мог допустить ошибку?

Вот сообщение которое я пытаюсь отправить:

```
var message = new gcm.Message({
    collapseKey: 'data',
    priority: 'high',
    contentAvailable: true,
    delayWhileIdle: false,
    timeToLive: 10000,

    data: {
        message: 'Message from gcm server',
        action: 'Update data on server'
    },

    notification: {
        tag : 'hasData',
        title: "My notification title",
        icon: "ic_launcher",
        color: "#22C064",
        sound: "jingle_bells_sms",
        soundname: "jingle_bells_sms",
        body: "This is a GCM notification that will be displayed ASAP.",
        click_action: "OPEN_APP"
    }
});
```